# Transpose data into rows, multiple columns

Tags: sas, transpose

My data looks like below:

```
ID   Month  Variable
1     1        Y
1     2        N
1     3        Y
2     1        Y
2     2        Y 
2     3        Y
```

I need to transpose it such that the ID and month are in rows and Variable values in columns
Outputdata:

```
ID  Month   Variable_Y  Variable_N
1     1       Y
1     2                     N
1     3       Y
2     1       Y
2     2       Y
2     3       Y
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried PROC TRANSPOSE? Post again with questions from your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PROC TRANSPOSE it's pretty straightforward.

```
proc transpose data=from out=transposed (drop=_name_)
 prefix=variable_
;
 by id month;
 id variable;
 var variable;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using a datastep:

```
data test_output (drop = variable);
  set test_input;
  format Variable_Y Variable_N $1.;

  if variable = "Y" then do;
     Variable_Y = "Y";
     call missing (Variable_N);
  end;

  else if variable = "N" then do;
     Variable_N = "N";
     call missing (Variable_Y);
  end;

 run;
```